# Most memory-efficient and fastest way to create a HashMap based on vector elements

Tags: rust

Let's say we read millions of items (from a DB table, JSON file, etc.) into `Vec<Item>`:

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Item {
    id: u64,
    name: String,
    //...
}
let items: Vec<Item> = load_items();
```

Very often, in order to process that data efficiently, we would need additional data structures, such as a HashMap with one of item's fields as a key and the item itself as a value. The simplest way to do that, in my view, is something like this:

```
let map_by_name: HashMap<String, Item> = items.iter().map(|x| (x.name.clone(), x.clone())).collect();
```

That's simple and easy. But here we **clone** all the data, which obviously isn't optimal in terms of performance and memory usage.

In GC-based languages (Java, .NET, Python, JS, etc.) this particular problem doesn't exist - the simplest and most natural implementation wouldn't involve cloning but only storing additional references to the objects in the vector.

In Rust, AFAIK, we cannot move or reference vector elements. So what would be the most efficient alternative then? The following ideas come to mind:

1. Using [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html):

```
let items: Vec<Rc<Item>> = load_items();
let map_by_name: HashMap<String, Rc<Item>> = items.iter().map(|x| (x.name.clone(), Rc::clone(&x))).collect();
```

2. In the HashMap value we only store the element's index in the vector:

```
let map_by_name: HashMap<String, usize> = items.iter().enumerate().map(|(i, x)| (x.name.clone(), i)).collect();
```

Is my understanding correct, that the second approach should be generally more efficient than the first, but it could be less convenient if we needed to pass the map to other functions, as it would always require us to pass the vector as well?

Also, is there a third approach that I am missing?

P.S.: In the examples above I used a cloned `String` as a key. It's clear we might also use `&str` obtained via `x.name.as_ref()` if that makes sense for a particular situation, but I wanted to particularly focus on the bigger problem - the items themselves.

Comment: If you don't need to mutate the elements or the `Vec`, the most efficient is probably: `let h: HashMap<&str, &Item> = items.iter().map (|i| (i.name.as_ref(), i)).collect();`

Comment: Thanks @Jmb! You are right! I still don't quite understand why one can get a reference this way but cannot directly reference by index. I guess it has something to do with the iterator?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple test, which compares the following:

1. `Vec<Item>`, `HashMap<String, Item>` (with cloning).
2. `Vec<Item>`, `HashMap<&str, &Item>`
3. `Vec<Rc<Item>>`, `HashMap<&str, Rc<Item>>`
4. `Vec<Item>`, `HashMap<&str, usize>`

I tested it several times, on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine, optimized in release mode. The results show that Variants 2 and 4 are the fastest. Variant 3 is slower, and 1 is of course the slowest. Note that in this test I only compare the time to *create* the vector and the HashMap. I haven't tested lookup times.

Here is the test code:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::time::Instant;

const CNT: u64 = 1_000_000;
const RUNS: usize = 6;

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Item {
    id: u64,
    name: String,
    //...
}

fn main() {
    println!("============ Clone ============");
    let t1 = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..RUNS {
        test_clone();
    }
    println!("Total: {} ms", (Instant::now() - t1).as_millis());
    println!("============ Refs =============");
    let t1 = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..RUNS {
        test_refs();
    }
    println!("Total: {} ms", (Instant::now() - t1).as_millis());
    println!("============ Rc =============");
    let t1 = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..RUNS {
        test_rc();
    }
    println!("Total: {} ms", (Instant::now() - t1).as_millis());
    println!("============ Index =============");
    let t1 = Instant::now();
    for _ in 0..RUNS {
        test_index();
    }
    println!("Total: {} ms", (Instant::now() - t1).as_millis());
    println!("===============================");
}

fn test_clone() {
    let t1 = Instant::now();
    let items: Vec<Item> = (0..CNT).map(|i| Item { id: i, name: format!("Abc {}", i) }).collect();
    let t2 = Instant::now();
    let h: HashMap<String, Item> = items.iter().map(|i| (i.name.clone(), i.clone())).collect();
    let t3 = Instant::now();
    let t = (items.len(), h.len());
    println!("Elapsed: {:4} ms  ({:4} for vec, {:4} ms for map). Items: {:?}", (t3 - t1).as_millis(), (t2 - t1).as_millis(), (t3 - t2).as_millis(), t);
}

fn test_refs() {
    let t1 = Instant::now();
    let items: Vec<Item> = (0..CNT).map(|i| Item { id: i, name: format!("Abc {}", i) }).collect();
    let t2 = Instant::now();
    let h: HashMap<&str, &Item> = items.iter().map(|i| (i.name.as_ref(), i)).collect();
    let t3 = Instant::now();
    let t = (items.len(), h.len());
    println!("Elapsed: {:4} ms  ({:4} for vec, {:4} ms for map). Items: {:?}", (t3 - t1).as_millis(), (t2 - t1).as_millis(), (t3 - t2).as_millis(), t);
}

fn test_rc() {
    let t1 = Instant::now();
    let items: Vec<Rc<Item>> = (0..CNT).map(|i| Rc::new(Item { id: i, name: format!("Abc {}", i) })).collect();
    let t2 = Instant::now();
    let h: HashMap<&str, Rc<Item>> = items.iter().map(|i| (i.name.as_ref(), Rc::clone(i))).collect();
    let t3 = Instant::now();
    let t = (items.len(), h.len());
    println!("Elapsed: {:4} ms  ({:4} for vec, {:4} ms for map). Items: {:?}", (t3 - t1).as_millis(), (t2 - t1).as_millis(), (t3 - t2).as_millis(), t);
}

fn test_index() {
    let t1 = Instant::now();
    let items: Vec<Item> = (0..CNT).map(|i| Item { id: i, name: format!("Abc {}", i) }).collect();
    let t2 = Instant::now();
    let h: HashMap<&str, usize> = items.iter().enumerate().map(|(i, x)| (x.name.as_ref(), i)).collect();
    let t3 = Instant::now();
    let t = (items.len(), h.len());
    println!("Elapsed: {:4} ms  ({:4} for vec, {:4} ms for map). Items: {:?}", (t3 - t1).as_millis(), (t2 - t1).as_millis(), (t3 - t2).as_millis(), t);
}
```

And the results:

```
============ Clone ============
Elapsed:  419 ms  ( 189 for vec,  230 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  564 ms  ( 363 for vec,  200 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  425 ms  ( 188 for vec,  237 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  372 ms  ( 168 for vec,  204 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  365 ms  ( 167 for vec,  197 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  394 ms  ( 173 for vec,  221 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Total: 4139 ms
============ Refs =============
Elapsed:  242 ms  ( 170 for vec,   71 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  259 ms  ( 187 for vec,   71 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  241 ms  ( 169 for vec,   71 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  243 ms  ( 168 for vec,   75 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  240 ms  ( 168 for vec,   72 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  239 ms  ( 169 for vec,   69 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Total: 1678 ms
============ Rc =============
Elapsed:  274 ms  ( 201 for vec,   73 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  272 ms  ( 199 for vec,   73 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  276 ms  ( 201 for vec,   74 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  278 ms  ( 201 for vec,   76 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  280 ms  ( 203 for vec,   76 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  286 ms  ( 211 for vec,   74 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Total: 2297 ms
============ Index =============
Elapsed:  243 ms  ( 170 for vec,   73 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  244 ms  ( 172 for vec,   72 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  240 ms  ( 168 for vec,   71 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  245 ms  ( 172 for vec,   73 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  243 ms  ( 170 for vec,   73 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Elapsed:  243 ms  ( 171 for vec,   72 ms for map). Items: (1000000, 1000000)
Total: 1664 ms
===============================
```

Apart from the times in individual iterations, we should also take note of the "Total" elapsed time for each test type. It includes significantly more extra elapsed time between the separate runs of a test for the `Rc` and especially the `Clone` variants. I presume the reason behind that is that with those variants there is a lot more data that needs to be *dropped* at the end of each `test_*` function call.

Comment: In your benchmark vec.len() == hash_map.len(). Try with N% of the keys being duplicate (N somewhat representative of production use case). And if you want to speed up further you could try with a faster hash function (Rust is using cryptographic hash function by default for all hash maps), for example: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustc-hash

Comment: @stepan I am aware that Rust is not using the fastest hash function by default, but I wouldn't expect a different hash function to significantly affect the ranking. The point here was to **compare** the different methods, not to aim for the lowest absolute execution times possible.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the index - your second example - is not necessarily more efficient/faster, because an `Rc<T>` is just a pointer to a `RcInner<T>`, which holds the reference counters and the `T`. In fact, an `Rc<T>` has the same size as a `usize`-index. Lookup time is basically the same, as indexing into the `Vec` and dereferencing the `T` from `Rc<T>` is basically the memory fetch. There is however more overhead with `Rc<T>` when the lookup-map is created because the reference counters of `Rc<Item>` need to be increased, while the index approach just assumes that the items will be where they were originally found.

The last point is what would inform me about which approach to choose: If the `Vec<Item>` and the `HashMap<Key, usize>` can be tightly coupled - for instance, in the same struct or the same function, where they can't escape - then it's probably just more convenient to use indexes.

However, if the lookup-maps float around, there is always the danger that the index held in the map gets out of whack as the `Vec` changes (e.g. someone, later on, might put in code which sorts the `Vec` after the indexes have been collected, destroying the coupling). If the lookup-maps are exposed to an API's caller, I'd go with the `Rc<Item>` to *guarantee* that the lookup-map only contains valid references.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When initially creating `Vec<Rc<Item>>` that should have some overhead compared to `Vec<Item>`. Perhaps not very significant though. I'm not sure about the HashMap access time. There shouldn't be a huge difference, but I don't know all the details. I guess it also depends on the memory allocator, which might also impact CPU cache hit ratio, etc.

Comment: @at54321 why don't you benchmark it ? You can use the awesome `criterion` library for Rust

Answer (score 0):

To me the questions was mainly focused around memory, so I benchmarked it for memory using size_of crate, criterion and User's at54321 code for comparison:

```rs
use criterion::{ criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion};
use size_of::SizeOf;

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::rc::Rc;


#[derive(Clone, Debug, SizeOf)]
struct Item {
    id: u64,
    name: String,
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);

pub fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
    println!("============ Clone ============");
    c.bench_function("Cloning: 1000 entities", |b| {
        b.iter(|| test_clone(1000, false))
    });
    c.bench_function("Cloning: 1000000 entities", |b| {
        b.iter(|| test_clone(1000000, false))
    });

    test_clone(1000, true);
    test_clone(1000000, true);

    println!("============ Refs =============");
    c.bench_function("Refs: 1000 entities", |b| {
        b.iter(|| test_refs(1000, false))
    });
    c.bench_function("Refs: 1000000 entities", |b| {
        b.iter(|| test_refs(1000000, false))
    });

    test_refs(1000, true);
    test_refs(1000000, true);

    println!("============ Rc =============");
    c.bench_function("RCs: 1000 entities", |b| {
        b.iter(|| test_rc(1000, false))
    });
    c.bench_function("RCs: 1000000 entities", |b| {
        b.iter(|| test_rc(1000000, false))
    });

    test_rc(1000, true);
    test_rc(1000000, true);

    println!("============ Index =============");
    c.bench_function("Indexes: 1000 entities", |b| {
        b.iter(|| test_index(1000, false))
    });
    c.bench_function("Indexes: 1000000 entities", |b| {
        b.iter(|| test_index(1000000, false))
    });

    test_index(1000, true);
    test_index(1000000, true);

}

fn test_clone(cnt_var: u64, should_print: bool) {
    let items: Vec<Item> = (0..cnt_var).map(|i| Item { id: i, name: format!("Abc {}", i) }).collect();
    let h: HashMap<String, Item> = items.iter().map(|i| (i.name.clone(), i.clone())).collect();

    if should_print {
        println!("Size of {} Clone HashMap: {:?}", cnt_var, h.size_of());
        println!("Size of {} Clone Vec: {:?}", cnt_var, items.size_of());
    }
}

fn test_refs(cnt_var: u64, should_print: bool) {
    let items: Vec<Item> = (0..cnt_var).map(|i| Item { id: i, name: format!("Abc {}", i) }).collect();
    let h: HashMap<&str, &Item> = items.iter().map(|i| (i.name.as_ref(), i)).collect();

    if should_print {
        println!("Size of {} Refs HashMap: {:?}", cnt_var, h.size_of());
        println!("Size of {} Refs Vec: {:?}", cnt_var, items.size_of());
    }
}

fn test_rc(cnt_var: u64, should_print: bool) {
    let items: Vec<Rc<Item>> = (0..cnt_var).map(|i| Rc::new(Item { id: i, name: format!("Abc {}", i) })).collect();
    let h: HashMap<&str, Rc<Item>> = items.iter().map(|i| (i.name.as_ref(), Rc::clone(i))).collect();

    if should_print {
        println!("Size of {} RCs HashMap: {:?}", cnt_var, h.size_of());
        println!("Size of {} RCs Vec: {:?}", cnt_var, items.size_of());
    }
}

fn test_index(cnt_var: u64, should_print: bool) {
    let items: Vec<Item> = (0..cnt_var).map(|i| Item { id: i, name: format!("Abc {}", i) }).collect();
    let h: HashMap<&str, usize> = items.iter().enumerate().map(|(i, x)| (x.name.as_ref(), i)).collect();

    if should_print {
        println!("Size of {} Index HashMap: {:?}", cnt_var, h.size_of());
        println!("Size of {} Index Vec: {:?}", cnt_var, items.size_of());
    }
}
```

Results are:

```
============ Clone ============
Cloning: 1000 entities  time:   [147.76 µs 150.60 µs 154.15 µs]
Found 17 outliers among 100 measurements (17.00%)
  1 (1.00%) high mild
  16 (16.00%) high severe

Cloning: 1000000 entities: time:   [525.85 ms 532.25 ms 539.09 ms]
Found 11 outliers among 100 measurements (11.00%)
  10 (10.00%) high mild
  1 (1.00%) high severe

Size of 1000 Clone HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 130572, excess_bytes: 59736, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 2001 }
Size of 1000 Clone Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 40024, excess_bytes: 1110, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1001 }
Size of 1000000 Clone HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 139315500, excess_bytes: 62537664, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 2000001 }
Size of 1000000 Clone Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 47920024, excess_bytes: 6031110, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1000001 }

============ Refs =============
Refs: 1000 entities     time:   [75.551 µs 78.979 µs 82.558 µs]
Found 17 outliers among 100 measurements (17.00%)
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  14 (14.00%) high severe

Refs: 1000000 entities  time:   [219.28 ms 222.75 ms 226.50 ms]
Found 1 outliers among 100 measurements (1.00%)
  1 (1.00%) high mild

Size of 1000 Refs HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 51256, excess_bytes: 26200, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1 }
Size of 1000 Refs Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 40024, excess_bytes: 1110, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1001 }
Size of 1000000 Refs HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 52428856, excess_bytes: 27428800, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1 }
Size of 1000000 Refs Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 47920024, excess_bytes: 6031110, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1000001 }

============ Rc =============
RCs: 1000 entities      time:   [110.63 µs 117.17 µs 124.82 µs]
Found 13 outliers among 100 measurements (13.00%)
  13 (13.00%) high severe

RCs: 1000000 entities   time:   [320.45 ms 324.97 ms 329.94 ms]
Found 14 outliers among 100 measurements (14.00%)
  7 (7.00%) high mild
  7 (7.00%) high severe

Size of 1000 RCs HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 91256, excess_bytes: 27310, shared_bytes: 40000, distinct_allocations: 2001 }
Size of 1000 RCs Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 48024, excess_bytes: 1110, shared_bytes: 40000, distinct_allocations: 2001 }
Size of 1000000 RCs HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 100348856, excess_bytes: 33459910, shared_bytes: 47920000, distinct_allocations: 2000001 }
Size of 1000000 RCs Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 55920024, excess_bytes: 6031110, shared_bytes: 47920000, distinct_allocations: 2000001 }

============ Index =============
Indexes: 1000 entities  time:   [73.632 µs 76.370 µs 79.756 µs]
Found 3 outliers among 100 measurements (3.00%)
  2 (2.00%) high mild
  1 (1.00%) high severe

Indexes: 1000000 entities: time:   [217.83 ms 221.13 ms 224.78 ms]
Found 15 outliers among 100 measurements (15.00%)
  4 (4.00%) high mild
  11 (11.00%) high severe

Size of 1000 Index HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 51256, excess_bytes: 26200, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1 }
Size of 1000 Index Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 40024, excess_bytes: 1110, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1001 }
Size of 1000000 Index HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 52428856, excess_bytes: 27428800, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1 }
Size of 1000000 Index Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 47920024, excess_bytes: 6031110, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1000001 }
```

EDIT:
Depending on the situation, even BOX might help:
Depending on the application and usage, even Box might help:

```
Box: 1000 entities      time:   [105.45 µs 108.84 µs 113.61 µs]
Found 13 outliers among 100 measurements (13.00%)
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  10 (10.00%) high severe

Benchmarking Box: 1000000 entities: Warming up for 3.0000 s
Box: 1000000 entities   time:   [288.40 ms 291.78 ms 295.87 ms]
Found 6 outliers among 100 measurements (6.00%)
  3 (3.00%) high mild
  3 (3.00%) high severe

Size of 1000 Boxes HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 51256, excess_bytes: 26200, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1 }
Size of 1000 Boxes Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 48024, excess_bytes: 1110, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 2001 }
Size of 1000000 Boxes HashMap: TotalSize { total_bytes: 52428856, excess_bytes: 27428800, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 1 }
Size of 1000000 Boxes Vec: TotalSize { total_bytes: 55920024, excess_bytes: 6031110, shared_bytes: 0, distinct_allocations: 2000001 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention (emphasis mine):

> In Rust, AFAIK, we cannot **move** or reference vector elements.

We actually can move the elements out of the vector! Assuming you don't need to keep the vector, we can use the [drain()](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.drain) method to move all the elements out of the vector and into a hashmap like so:

```rust
let map_by_name: HashMap<String, Item> = items.drain(..)
    .map(|x| (x.name.clone(), x)).collect();
```